# What for are JSON schemas practically used?

Tags: c++, json, jsonschema

Reference: [Getting started with JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html)

I have been reading about JSON schema. I understand that

> When you’re talking about a data format, you want to have metadata
> about what keys mean, including the valid inputs for those keys. JSON
> Schema is a proposed IETF standard how to answer those questions for
> data.

Alright, so these schemas define what is and what is not permitted in the JSON structure I am building.

My question is, how are these schemas practically used? For example if I am using a JSON file in a C++ program (or a python script), I can use the json file as it is (of course without any validation). But if I want to validate it, how can I use the json schemas to do that? <strike>Are there any recommended libraries for that?</strike> (I am interested in C++ but additional info on python would be welcomed too)

EDIT: I would like to emphasize that the **main purpose** of this question is to understand ***how are these schemas practically used?***
Are schemas used only for validation? or are there other uses? (I am new to the concept of schemas)

Comment: https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: The schemas are different methods of structuring data for serialization.  They are not a requirement to using json.  Json's flexibility and readability are what make it so popular

Comment: @JohnGordon Excellent! Thanks. I think my side question with python is solved. I wonder about C++...

Comment: "how are these schemas practically used?" By supplying them to a third-party validation library, as you seem to have guessed. "Are there any recommended libraries for that?" Recommendations of this sort [are explicitly off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) by yourself for this sort of thing, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+json+schema+validator). (You may find old Stack Overflow questions this way that were asked before changes to the rules.)

Comment: (That said, I strongly recommend against trying to use C++ for heavy string manipulation tasks, including working with JSON data. Even with `std::string`, the language simply is not designed from the ground up for such tasks, in particular for dealing with the various quirks of Unicode.)

Comment: I am modifying a code already written in C++ so I have no option on that. Right now it uses JSON files but not schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use is **validation**. More than pass/fail you get a meaningful error message like e.g. "unexpected value `W` for field `A.B.C`, allowed values are `X, Y, Z`" or "invalid type for field `A.B.C`, expected date, found int", "missing field A.B.C" etc.

They can also serve as self **documentation**.

They are also used for **autocomplete**. For instance a json setting file for a program like VS Code. When you edit the `settings.json` or `c_cpp_properties.json` from within VS Code you get autocomplete for that particular json file. That is built in. But you can also define your own schemas with file pattern match and and you can get autocomplete in the editor for your own json files.

Answer (score 4):

The implementations page on the JSON Schema website lists several usecases.
https://json-schema.org/implementations.html

- validation
- Code generation
- UI generation
- Sample data generation

JSON Schema is only designed for validation, however other use cases are possible, and we are trying to formalise semantics and additional keywords to make other usecases work interoperably.

Further, if you'd like to hear about real world use cases, there's a series on the official YouTube channel: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHVhS4Tj1YZOrrvl7_a9LaBAtst7BWH8a

There are also some case studies found on the blog: https://json-schema.org/blog